# how to construct an array with specific element size in python3?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

you might ask "why don't you just use C?", 
but I would like to try constructing an array 
with specific element size using python 3, is that possible?

I know bytearray() but it's limited to one byte per element, is there a more flexible function?

also, is there any equivalent statement in python 3 to "sizeof(int)" in C? 
I am not talking about sys.getsizeof(int) since it gives me the bytesize of the whole int class

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = [None]*10
```

This will initialize a list with size 10, but you can also take a look at arrays from the numpy module. This will also have lots of other optimization in it too.

I don't have much experience with your memory problem, but maybe this code will help? http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546530/